# Weighted mean by row

Tags: r

I have the following data:

```
a=c(1:10)
b=c(16:25)
c=c(24:33)
wa=c(3,7,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,1)
wb=c(3,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,8)
wc=c(4,1,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,1)
z=data.frame(a,b,c,wa,wb,wc)
```

I want to get the weighted mean for each record.  So I tried this:

```
weight=apply(subset(z,select=c(wa,wb,wc)),1,function(x) x)
z$weightMean=apply(subset(z,select=c(a,b,c)),1,function(x) weighted.mean(x,weight))
```

Which returned the following error message:

```
Error in weighted.mean.default(x, weight) : 
  'x' and 'w' must have the same length
```

So then I tried this:

```
weight=as.vector(weight)
z$weightMean=apply(subset(z,select=c(a,b,c)),1,function(x) weighted.mean(x,weight))
```

Which also returned the same error.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This seems to do the trick:

```
> apply(z, 1, function(x) weighted.mean(x[1:3], x[4:6]))
 [1] 14.7  7.3 16.7 17.7 18.7 19.7 20.7 21.7 22.7 24.3
```

This will probably be a bit faster, though less clear as to what's going on:

```
> rowSums(z[,1:3] * z[,4:6]) / rowSums(z[,4:6])
 [1] 14.7  7.3 16.7 17.7 18.7 19.7 20.7 21.7 22.7 24.3
```

Comment: Only the first method can deal with NA values, using `weighted.mean(..., na.rm=T)`. The second method returns NA as soon as one of the columns contains NA.

Comment: @Martin - `rowSums()` supports the `na.rm` argument, so it should work for that one as well.